# A question about series convergence at a given point if functional series uniform convergence on interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Could you give me some hint how to prove this statement:
If $f_n(x)$ is continuous sequence on [0,1] and the series $\sum_{n\ge1}f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on [0,1) then the series $\sum_{n\ge1}f_n(1)$ converges.

I have no idea how to start.

Thanks.

Comment: Are we assuming measure theory knowledge?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Hint)** Use in some way the inequality$$|s_m(1)-s_n(1)|\le$$$$|s_m(1)-s_m(x)|+|s_m(x)-s_n(x)|+|s_n(x)-s_n(1)|$$ where $s_n$ is a partial sum.

Comment: @Goos See H.S.Carslaw An Introduction to the Theory of Fourier Series and Integrals 1930, p. 154 .

Comment: @Goos Let $N$ be such that for $m, n > N$, $|s_m(x) - s_n(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for any $x \in [0,1)$. Now, for any couple $m, n > N$, you can find a $x \in [0,1)$ satisfying my inequality. If you change the couple, you use (and you can do) another $x$, if it is necessary.

Comment: @Goos I gave OP only a hint ...I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: @Goos Read [my reference (earlier ed. 1921)](https://ia600305.us.archive.org/20/items/introductiontoth00carsrich/introductiontoth00carsrich.pdf) pp. 137-138 .

Comment: Yes, I understand the argument.  For some reason I thought you were suggesting to fix some $x$ independent of $m, n$.  Also, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$.
For each $n$, $s_n =  \sum_{i=1}^n f_i$ is continuous at $1$.
Therefore, for each $n$ we can pick $\delta_n > 0$
such that for any $|y - 1| \le \delta_n$, $|s_n(y) - s_n(1)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$.
We can further guarentee that $\delta_n$ is decreasing.

Now, choose $N$ such that for $m, n > N$, $|s_m(x) - s_n(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for any $x \in [0,1)$.
Then for $m > n > N$,
\begin{align*}
\quad &\left| s_m(1) - s_n(1) \right| \\
&\le
\left| s_m(1) - s_m(1 - \delta_m) \right|
+ \left| s_m(1 - \delta_m) - s_n(1 - \delta_m) \right|
+ \left| s_n(1 - \delta_m) - s_n(1) \right| \\
\end{align*}
All terms are $< \frac{\epsilon}{3}$, the first two terms directly and the
third since $\delta_m < \delta_n$.